# How to extract folder name as a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have directory

> MainProject/src/

My script which I am calling `test.sh` run at /MainProject/ and here is some part of the sript:

```
dotnet restore src/*.sln
dotnet msbuild -t:publish src/*.sln -p:Configuration=Release
```

For this command, I want MainProject.Test as variable VAR:

```
dotnet vstest VAR/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/VAR.dll
```

or something like this:

```
dotnet vstest {src/*.Test}/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/{src/*Test}.dll
```

Which contains these files and folders:

Files:

> project.sln
>
> somescript.sh

Folders:

> MainProject.Test
>
> MainProject.Host

What I need to do is fetch `MainProject.Test` folder name and set it to a variable, but I also need it to be templatized where I can set it to a variable using something like `*.Test`

The reason for this is that I need the script parametrized because there are

> MainProject2
>
> MainProject3
>
> MainProjectx

using the same naming convention.

Comment: Is the path to `MainProject.Test` where your script is run? Where the source to the script itself lives? An argument? Something else?

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within -- right now, the question is too vague to be certain.

Comment: (when you say "fetch `MainProject.Test`" -- do you mean fetch it *from the command line*? Or fetch it from where?)

Comment: I updated the question. I just want `MainProject.Test` foldername as a string to pass as a variable

Comment: Yes, but where does it (do you want it to) come from in the first place? Does it come from a command-line argument to your script? Does it come from looking up what the current directory was when your script was started?

Comment: I want it to come from the same script. As in when the shell script runs the script knows the current directory which is /MainProject/

Comment: Sorry if I am being confusing, I am very new to shell scripting.

Answer (score 3):

The current directory is in `$PWD`. That's fully-qualified; to remove everything from the beginning up to the last `/` would be `${PWD##*/}`, using a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Thus, to extract the last piece of the current working directory and add `.Test` as a suffix:

```
result=${PWD##*/}.Test
```

Comment: How would you extract the second to last directory, i.e. move up one dir at a time, only capturing that individual directory?

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out what I want, but it's not really scalable:

`PWD="/system/dir/path/project/client"`

`APP_NAME=${PWD%/*}`

`APP_NAME=${APP_NAME##*/}`

`echo ${APP_NAME}`

--> `project`

Comment: @JunoSprite, what do you mean "not really scaleable"? Yes, it's three lines, but they're all shell builtins, so far faster than running a single external command. The only part of the code in your comment above that has anything wrong with it is the [`echo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566); and I suppose I could also quibble about the all-caps `APP_NAME` variable name being out of compliance with [relevant POSIX recommendations](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which reserve lower-case variable names for application use.

Comment: Not scalable, meaning it doesn't work for getting an arbitrary dir's name from an arbitrary path length. Say I wanted to get the third-to-last dir name into a variable? or forth-to-last? I'm not good enough with RegEx to solve that quite yet. Ideally, I'd have a RegEx with '1' or '2' or '3', etc, written somewhere in the expression, which would allow me to grab the first, second, third, etc, dir name from either the beginning or the end of a given path, and store that name into a variable. I'd be able to easily swap out the number corresponding to the depth of the dir name I seek

Comment: `IFS=/ read -r -a pieces <<<"$APP_NAME"` then, and you can pick out the piece you want from the array.